# Huawei Ascend P6, Moving maps to external sdcard

Tags: external-sd, internal-storage, storage, maps, huawei

I bought an Huawei Ascend P6, which comes with 8GB internal phone storage. But only ~4GB are available for the "internal storage".

I installed my apps, which include Tomtom Europe and Copilot Europe, which respectively have maps of about 4 and 2 GB. Both of them only install the offline maps in the internal memory for this phone.

I am trying to find a way to install those maps into the external SD.

I tried, without success, the following solutions

- trying to move the apps to SD card after installing the maps. The App gets moved, but the maps remain in the internal storage.
- trying to create a symbolic link installing a terminal app and using the `ln -s` command. But it doesn't work since the /mnt/sdcard (internal memory) is VFAT.
- I tried some apps to move applications to the external SD card, but no success yet. (tried Link2SD)

Any help would be appreciated.

I read that FolderMount App can solve the problem, but it only works for rooted device. But my device isn't rooted (so, if anyone does have a good tutorial on how to root this device, it would be appreciated). But if possible, I would avoid rooting.

I still have the last try in the arsenal, which is enabling the debug mode in the cell phone and trying to use the command `pm set-install-location 2` via adb or a terminal emulator app. I didn't try this yet, since at the moment my phone is installing the firmware update.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no solution without rooting the device. Only things I know for such cases are *FolderMount* (as you already mention) and *DirectoryBind*; both require root access. That only leaves to either root your device, or have the resp. devs fixing it in their apps.

Comment: the `pm set-install-location 2` command didn't solve. I saw that modifying the app configuration files manually in a special "procedure" can address the issue for co-pilot. I am sure that the same thing can be achieved by altering the files (`currentmap.dat` which is binary and `.metadata.xml` and maybe some other files). Those are the last resource I'll try tonight, then I'll give up and start trolling on the support forums for those apps.

Comment: I solved the issue this way: I sold the Huawei Ascend P6, and bought a Google Nexus 5. And it works much better.

Comment: I was just about asking you to make that an answer – but for obvious reasons, that doesn't make much sense :) Glad the problem is solved for you, though I'm less happy about the kind of solution it required… Still wondering how you're moving apps to the external SD card on a Nexus 5, though #D